# HTML internal link not working properly

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to create an internal link on an aspx page. Below is a simplified version of my code:

```
<a href="Agenda.aspx/#speaker">Speaker Name</a>
```

and it links the following:

```
<p id="speaker">Speaker Name<br> </p>
```

Initially this works fine, if the link is clicked it takes me to the correct point on the page.

The address in the address bar would be:

..../Agenda.aspx/#speaker

However, if I scroll back up to the link and click on it again, it will put the following address in the address bar:

..../Agenda.aspx/Agenda.aspx/#speaker

Which is clearly wrong.

Aside from the fact I do not want it to do this, and it is unprofessional, when the page displays in this way, the images do not appear.

What am I doing wrong and how can I correct it. I do not even know what to search for to find a relevant question to help me solve this.

Comment: can you use `href="#speaker"`  only in the link

Comment: Yes. agree with dvhh. you can also check http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp for further reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with in this page, you shoud not keep the same page name, the correct one is

```
<a href="#speaker">Speaker Name</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<a href="Agenda.aspx#speaker">Speaker Name</a>
```

Comment: with in this page, you shoud not keep the same page name, the correct one is <a href="#speaker">Speaker Name</a>

Comment: My answer will work in case of redirection of page and page exist an hyperlink with #speaker id

Comment: ya, but he says directly,  it is in internal link on an aspx page